# How to change the name of my symlink?

Tags: xubuntu

totally new here. Using Ubuntu on windows 10 I created a bad symlink using:

```
ln -s C:\Users\Andres\Documents\mnt\c\Users\andres\Documents documents
```

later I did it right by:

```
ln -s ../../mnt/c/Users/Andres/Documents documents2
```

But, I want to erase to first one and rename the second one, how do I do it ?

Comment: I have no experience with Ubuntu on WSL, but on a pure posix/unix/Ubuntu/GNU system I'd use `rm` to remove the unwanted symlink, and `mv` to rename (`mv` is usually simpler than `rename`)

Answer (score 2):

In the same location:

```
unlink documents
```

Assuming you want to rename `documents2` to `documents`

```
mv documents2 documents
```